# Java: DefaultMutableTreeNode Event When Renamed

Tags: java, swing, rename, jtree, treenode

I created a class that extends DefaultMutableTreeNode. It has a variable, "resource" of the type Resource so that it can be linked to an object without that object affecting its name. The Resource class has a variable, "name" that I would like to be changed when its corresponding DefaultMutableTreeNode is renamed, but I can't find any such events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DefaultTreeCellEditor there is this method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellEditor.html#addCellEditorListener(javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener)

Comment: Thank you! I'd looked there, but I guess I didn't know exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @jimn346 you should mark the question answered if that solved your problem