# Java - JTree UpdateUI Not Working in Runnable Jar

Tags: java, macos, swing, jtree, executable-jar

When I add a node to the JTree dynamically and call tree.updateUI() on Mac OSX, it works, but when I move the jar to Windows, it does not update the tree. This is only in the runnable jar mode. If I just run it in Eclipse, it works just right.

In Windows, I suppose that it sort of updates it by showing there is a child node under the root node, but does not display the child node. It should be showing the child node as well.

What should I try to solve this problem?

Is it how I build the runnable jar? I used Eclipse export thingy. If so, is there a better way to make it?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `updateUI()` method is not intended for this use. Instead, tell the tree model to [`reload()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#reload%28javax.swing.tree.TreeNode%29) the affected node, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639595/230513).