# Assign unique ID to a DefaultMutableTreeNode in a JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

I have a Jtree that I can add new Nodes to. I need to assign a unique ID to each new node.
I was thinking of extending the DefaultMutableTreeNode Class but I guess it didn't work or I did it wrong.

So, how can I do this. An example would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: If you showed us what you tried, we could tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: [this code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/implementsTreeModel.htm)  you can to use for your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and/or with detailed describtion about

Comment: @JBNizet I already deleted it. Would extending it work? If it does can you give an example, I suppose it's pretty short?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out and it WORKS :)
I extednded DefaultMutableTreeNode:

```
 public class MyTreeNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {

    public int ID;

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public MyTreeNode(String title) {
        setUserObject(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for this. You can pass any `Object` as user object, which includes an object containing that ID.

Comment: See the linked example in @trashgod comment on the other answer

Answer (score 2):

My impression is that DefaultMutableTreeNode works "best" without extending it, but wrapping your own user-defined object. And that could have an ID.

Nevertheless your way should work too, when creating a nodes children with your own class. A matter of debugging, and trace logs: creation of all objects and such. Mind that one can easily err in the API and several times create TreeNode-s for a child.

Comment: +1 That's been my experience; there's an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513).