# DefaultMutableTreeNode inbuilt tree structure

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treemodel

How can I access `userObject` in `DefaultMutableTreeNode`
How can I modify the user object or extract the values defined in it?

Comment: how about reading its api doc?

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the methods `setUserObject` and `getUserObject`?

Comment: my object contains an int p and char a
and I add this to my structure
DefaultMutableTreeNode node=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(this object);
using get methods the object returned loses identity for p and a
and I am not able to access or modify them.

Comment: @kamikaze: You can cast the outout of `getUserObject` to the required type since you know what type you have put into the node. After casting you can access your `p` and `a` again. The syntax if `MyType item = (MyType)node.getUserObject(); item.p....`

Comment: thnx A.H. 
that was very naive