# Java JTable, how to change cell data (write text in)?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, tablemodel

Am looking to change a cell's data in a jtable. How can I do this? When I execute the following code I get errors.

```
JFrame f= new JFrame();
final JTable table= new JTable(10,5);

TableModelListener tl= new TableModelListener(){
  public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){

    table.setValueAt("hello world",2,2);
  }
};

table.getModel().addTableModelListener(tl);
f.add(table);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

I have also tried this below but it still doesn't work. What gives?

```
table.getModel().setValueAt("hello world",2,2);
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by _doesn't work_?

Comment: It doesn't compile. My problem is simple: when a jtable cell value is changed, I want to edit a particular cell

Comment: then fix the compilation errors first ..

Comment: Oh, my bad. It compiles but doesn't run.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `table.setValueAt()` within a `TableModelListener` causes the `tableChanged()` method 
to be called followed by the `setValueAt()` method being called again and so on *ad infinitum*, resulting in a `StackOverflowError`.

One solution is to use a `CellEditorListener` instead. See this [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20100727035247/http://www.gammelsaeter.com/programming/simple-celleditorlistener-example-in-java/).

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem. When something happens to a jtable, how would I be able to write to a cell?

Comment: I think you're looking for a `CellEditorListener`. See the link to the example above.

Comment: `tableChanged` is telling you something has ALREADY happened

Comment: @Reimeus the link is now broken.  Is there another example you know of?  Perhaps on SO?

Comment: see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107984/get-edited-treenode-from-a-celleditorlistener/11113648#11113648) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rob Camick's example that help me alot, in addition you can get old and new value also by using this class. 
[Example](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/)!

Also look at the end of Blog to see my post to Add Addiional Code to the Form Load Event To Handle Last Change Occur To Your Table.

```
 MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent(tblDetailInfo, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 1, false);
for(MouseListener ml: tblDetailInfo.getMouseListeners()){
ml.mouseClicked(me); }
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't what i'm looking for either. My problem is simple: when a jtable cell value is changed, I want to edit a particular cell.