# Java swing - How to set specify tree node editable instead of the whole tree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I need a JTree that only the leaf node can be editable. But I don't know how to make the custom setting. Is there anyone can help? Thx!

Comment: Where's your code? What's your question?

Answer (score 5):

You can override the [`isCellEditable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellEditor.html#isCellEditable-java.util.EventObject-) method of [`DefaultTreeCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellEditor.html)  in a way that limits editing to leaf nodes, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513).

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
    return super.isCellEditable(e)
        && ((TreeNode) lastPath.getLastPathComponent()).isLeaf();
}
```

Comment: personally, I don't like the idea of letting the editor decide about model-related editability. But then, TreeModel unfortunately doesn't have a notion of editability, so one hack is as good or bad as the other :-) Which would be to override JTree.isPathEditable.