# DocumentListener for DefaultMutableTreeNode

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtree, documentlistener

I want to listen to text changes when the user is editing the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` when the `JTree` is set editable. Like, i want to display a status label of what the user is typing in the node.

Unfortunately, i didn't find a `DocumentListener` for `DefaultMutableTreeNode` to listen to changes like inserting, deleting and modifying text in the `DefaultMutableTreeNode`.

Could any one say me how to do this? Any working answer is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Once the editor is prepared, you can add a `DocumentListener` to the  cell editor's `editingComponent`. Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513), add the following method to `MyTreeCellEditor`:

```
@Override
public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
    final Component c = super.getTreeCellEditorComponent(tree, value, isSelected, expanded, leaf, row);
    JTextField jtf = (JTextField) editingComponent;
    jtf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            print(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            print(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            print(e);
        }
        private void print(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    });
    return c;
}
```