# Generate output when editing of a cell is stopped or canceled

Tags: java, swing, jtable, celleditorlistener

I have a `JFrame` named 'NewJFrame' containing a `JTable` named 'inputTable'. I have an editor named 'myeditor1' which is an instance of the class MyEditor defined as follows :

```
private static class MyEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    public MyEditor(){
        super(new JTextField());
    }
}
```

I have defined a class 'MyCellEditorListener' as follows :

```
public class MyCellEditorListener implements CellEditorListener{
    public MyCellEditorListener(){

    }

    @Override
    public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Editing has been stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Editing has been canceled");
    }
}
```

inputTable's model is as follows :

```
inputTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
     }
) {
    Class[] types = new Class [] {
        java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Float.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class
    };

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return types [columnIndex];
    }
});
```

And the constructor of NewJFrame is :

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    MyEditor myeditor1 = new MyEditor();
    inputTable.setDefaultEditor(Integer.class, myeditor1);
    inputTable.setDefaultEditor(Float.class, myeditor1);
    myeditor1.addCellEditorListener(new MyCellEditorListener());

}
```

My first problem is that :

Whenever I stop editing any cell in the second column (which is of type `Float`), I get an exception saying that `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number` but this doesn't happen when I stop editing a cell of the first column (which is of type `Integer`). The output 'Editing has been stopped' is displayed in the second case but not in the first case !! Why is this happening and what should I do ?

My second problem is that :

Whenever I cancel editing a cell by pressing the `Esc` key, the expected output of 'Editing has been canceled' is not displayed. Why ? Shouldn't a `ChangeEvent` be triggered whenever I press the `Esc` key (while editing a cell of inputTable) ?

Thanks in advance

P.S : I am using Netbeans IDE 7.2 RC1.

Comment: For reference, here's a complete, working [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513) of adding a `CellEditorListener` to a `JTree`.

Comment: why do you want to listener to the editor (vs. listening to the model)? Anyway, you should post a SSCCE to demonstrate the problem