# Link between JTree and JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jtabbedpane

I've got a project in Java where I have a frame which is divided in 2 panels. The left panel consists of a `JTabbedPane` and the right panel of a `JTree`. These are 2 different classes. Now if I doubleclick on a item in the `Jtree`, I want the tabbed pane to switch to the tab about the node I pressed on and fill in the data.

For example when I press on a student, I want to jump to the student tab and fill in the details I can get out of the tree, name etc.

I know you can use a selection listener with the tree and use the setindexat for the tabs, but my biggest problem is I don't know how the classes can communicate with eachother.
Does anybody have a idea?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, please read all of this: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write an interface for a listener and make your tabbed pane implement that listener. The listener will basically listen to events generated by the tree. So have your tree also fire events whenever a double click is done on a particular item.

In the implementation of the listener, look for the child that is the item associated with that event and do your processing i.e. populate the tab.

Comment: @B13ZT: What listener interface did you decide to use?

Answer (score 1):

In your `TreeSelectionListener`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513), invoke `setSelectedIndex()` or `setSelectedComponent()`, discussed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), to select the tab corresponding to the selection. A `Map<TreeNode, Integer>` or `Map<TreeNode, Component>` may simplify identifying the correct tab.