# I have a JTree and I want to apply renderer so that I can modify the display name for the nodes of the JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

So that nodes have internally different name but shows other name, that would be easy for me to apply searching constraints on original name, but display modified name.

```
 treePanel = new JUResourceTypeTreeStructurePanel
 (I18N_ID, "menu.title", _panelBinding,VIEW_NAME,     
    masterBindings,MASTER_VIEW_SYNC,
    wizard,archiveAction,toggleAction,unArchiveAction,   
    copyAction, pasteAction
 );

 JUCtrlHierTypeBinding[] masterBindings = new JUCtrlHierTypeBinding[]
 {
   new JUTreeAccessorTypeBinding("NodeType1", MASTER_VIEW_CLASS, "NameDate", "Children", masterIcon, masterIcon, masterIcon)
 };
```

so here in master binf=ding namedate is passed, get path returns path of namedate type which is then selected through binding, whether the searching is made through any id,name etc. i want this NAMEDATE to be NAMEDATEID, for unique search path creation but to show only name as nodename.

```
DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer()
  {
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, Boolean selected, Boolean expanded, Boolean leaf, int row, Boolean hasFocus)
  {


    return super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
  } 
  };
```

_SelectPanel.getJUTree().setCellRenderer(renderer);

what methos is there to change the node name, can anybody suggest.

Comment: i have applied renderer and to binding i have passed a modified attribute name which i want to pass juresourcetypetreestructurepanel so that while searchin getpath() function returns treepath according to this node but iwant to show modified name in display of tree.

Comment: i need a general idea about how i should use render for this, can share code its confidential.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (an SSCCE is not your private code, but simply an example that concentrates on the exact problem).  Note the document is being reviewed and discussed on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214955/155831), contributions welcome.

Comment: @hashit I'm often in similar situations where my company doesn't like to share some code. Can you give us an idea, even in pseudo code or stripped down code?

Comment: yes wait as ppl are killing my reputation here.

Comment: please reply if you need more detail for my problem

Comment: See this Q&A about [proprietary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140847/163188) code.

Comment: Review complete.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Note that the code snippets so far posted are neither an SSCCE *nor* an MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513), `DefaultMutableTreeNode` "may also hold a reference to a user object." Your `userObject` can return the display name in `toString()`, while providing an accessor for the search name.

Addendum: *I need only the name to be shown there, not the date.*

The `getTreeCellRendererComponent()` method of `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` invokes "`convertValueToText()`, which ultimately invokes `toString()` on `value`." Your implementation should instead call `setText()` with your preferred value, perhaps derived from the value established by the `super` implementation.

Comment: but "namedate" is the complete node name of the tree, i need only name to be shown there not the date, while searching based on name date, no function there in renderer to override the name of node.